# How do I set a checkbox to True using Powershell when processing a form?

Tags: powershell, checkbox

I need to automate a couple of steps in in a remote website using Powershell.

I am using Invoke-WebRequest to fetch everything into $response which contains the element e.g. "checkboxelement"

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest 'www.site.com' -SessionVariable session
$form = $response.Forms[0]
$action = $form.Action
$mycheckbox = $response.ParsedHtml.getElementsByName("checkboxelement")
```

If I do

```
@($mycheckbox).checked
```

This returns

```
False
```

But I don't know how to set it to True so I can submit the form using another Invoke-WebRequest to the www.site.com/$form.Action

I have tried

```
$mycheckbox.checked = $true
```

But I get this error

```
The property 'checked' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:1 char:1
+ $mycheckbox.checked = $true
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

So all I want to do is change the element checked status to True. Any help?

Comment: `$($mycheckbox).checked = $true`

Comment: That works perfectly thanks! How do I mark this as the accepted answer? :)